# Concatenate number with string in Swift

Tags: string, nsstring, swift

I need to concatenate a `String` and `Int` as below:

```
let myVariable: Int = 8
return "first " + myVariable
```

But it does not compile, with the error:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'

What is the proper way to concatenate a String + Int?

Answer (score 82):

If you want to put a number inside a string, you can just use [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_380):

```
return "first \(myVariable)"
```

Comment: It give back "Optional(value)" when used like above.

Answer (score 63):

You have TWO options;

```
return "first " + String(myVariable)
```

or

```
return "first \(myVariable)"
```

Answer (score 8):

To add an Int to a String you can do:

```
return "first \(myVariable)"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing a lot of it, consider an operator to make it more readable:

```
func concat<T1, T2>(a: T1, b: T2) -> String {
    return "\(a)" + "\(b)"
}

let c = concat("Horse ", "cart") // "Horse cart"
let d = concat("Horse ", 17) // "Horse 17"
let e = concat(19.2345, " horses") // "19.2345 horses"
let f = concat([1, 2, 4], " horses") // "[1, 2, 4] horses"

operator infix +++ {}
@infix func +++ <T1, T2>(a: T1, b: T2) -> String {
    return concat(a, b)
}

let c1 = "Horse " +++ "cart"
let d1 = "Horse " +++ 17
let e1 = 19.2345 +++ " horses"
let f1 = [1, 2, 4] +++ " horses"
```

You can, of course, use any valid infix operator, not just `+++`.

Answer (score 3):

`Optional` keyword would appear when you have marked variable as optional with `!` during declaration.

To avoid Optional keyword in the print output, you have two options:

1. Mark the optional variable as non-optional. For this, you will have
   to give default value.
2. Use force unwrap `(!)` symbol, next to variable

In your case, this would work just fine

`return "first \(myVariable!)"`

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 2
var b = "Hello W"
print("\(a) " + b)
```

will print `2 Hello W`

Answer (score -3):

Here is documentation about [String and characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

```
var variableString = "Horse"
variableString += " and carriage"
// variableString is now "Horse and carriage"
```

Comment: The question is about concatenating it with an int.